# Bind event to wrapper element

Tags: jquery

Part of the jQuery plugin I'm writing involves wrapping the input `<div>` (the content) into a dynamically created `<div>` (the container).

My plugin then needs to add event handlers to the container div without changing the content div.

This is the simplest HTML I can write that describes my problem. If you display this and click on the container, the event does not fire:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var container = $('<div class="container">');           
            $('#content').wrap(container);          // (A)
            container.click(function(e){alert('clicked');}); // (B)
        });
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">the content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that if the lines marked (A) and (B) are switched around the code works as expected. I cannot do this in my plugin because my plugin is somewhat more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var container = $('<div class="container">');           
$('#content').wrap(container);          
var wrapper = $('#content').parent();
wrapper.click(function(e){alert('clicked');});
```

The wrap function makes copy of a wrapper element, it is not the same object.

From manual:

> The .wrap() function can take any string or object that could be passed to the $() factory function to specify a DOM structure. This structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only one inmost element. **A copy of this structure will be wrapped around** each of the elements in the set of matched elements. This method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily manage with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var container = $('<div class=" unique_container container">');           
            $('#content').wrap(container);          // (A)
           // container.click(function(e){alert('clicked');}); // (B)
        });
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">the content</div>
<script>
    $("body").delegate(".unique_container", "click", function() {
        alert('now it is clicked.');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please like the page if your problem is resolved.

http://justprogrammer.com/2013/06/25/jquery-basic-concepts/

Please add your uniqe container class here.

Comment: This will cause problems if there are more .container elements in document.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't play nicely with other .container elements as @PiotrUchman said, and as my project is a plugin I can't have that.